# How to set custom tick marks in Core Plot to icons?

Tags: image, plot, core-plot

Is there a way to make tick mark (major tick mark) to be UIImage (custom graphics) instead of text?
I have values in one of the axis I need to present as icons.
I do not see any delegate for this but maybe someone knows the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axis labels can have any `CPTLayer` (which is a direct subclass of Core Animation's `CALayer`) as its content. Set your image as the layer background and build a custom label using this layer. Several of the Core Plot example apps demonstrate custom labels, although they all use text labels.

You have two options for adding your custom labels to the graph:

1. Use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy. Create a `NSSet` containing your labels and set it to the `axisLabels` property on the axis. If you use this, remember that you must provide the major and/or minor tick locations in addition to the custom labels.
2. Use any other labeling policy to generate the tick locations and implement the `-axis:shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:` axis delegate method. In your delegate, create new labels at the provided locations and return `NO` to suppress the automatic labels.

Eric

Comment: Your answer took me quite far, but I am having issue with drawing icon itselt on a CPLayer. CPLayer is being drawn correctly but without image (layer's contents). See update to the question with code used.

Comment: When you say "create new labels at the provided locations" you mean the "tickLocation" property right?  I've been setting them in my delegate based on the argument from the delegate (locations) but they all are setup at location = 0.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting Eric's question and thanking him I provide working code for his suggested solution.
Maybe it helps someone:

```
if (yAxisIcons) {


    int custonLabelsCount = [self.yAxisIcons count];

    NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:custonLabelsCount];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < custonLabelsCount; i++) {

        NSNumber *tickLocation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        NSString *file = [yAxisIcons objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:file];

        CPImageLayer *layer; // My custom CPLayer subclass - see code below

          CGFloat nativeHeight = 1;
          CGFloat nativeWidth = 1;


        if (icon) {

            layer = [[CPImageLayer alloc] initWithImage:icon];
            nativeWidth = 20;//CGImageGetWidth(icon.CGImage);
            nativeHeight = 20;//CGImageGetHeight(icon.CGImage);
            //layer.contents = (id)icon.CGImage;

            if (nativeWidth > biggestCustomIconWidth) {
                biggestCustomIconWidth = nativeWidth;
            }

        }else{
            layer = [[CPImageLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
        }

            CGRect  startFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, nativeWidth, nativeHeight);

            layer.frame = startFrame;
            layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
            CPAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithContentLayer:layer];
            newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
            newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
            [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
            [newLabel release];
            [layer release];

    }

    y.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];

}
```

**CPImageLayer.h**

```
#import "CPLayer.h"

@interface CPImageLayer : CPLayer {

    UIImage *_image;

}
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

**CPImageLayer.m**

```
#import "CPImageLayer.h"
#import "CPLayer.h"

@implementation CPImageLayer

-(void)dealloc{

    [_image release];
    [super dealloc];
}
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image{

    CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:f]) {

        _image = [image retain];
    }

    return self;

}

-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, _image.CGImage);

}
@end
```

***Enjoy***