# CPTAxis delegate methods not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

```
// Grid line styles
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.6] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];

CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
x.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
x.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 4;
x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 1;

// pin axis to bottom
x.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

// Y axis
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
y.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
y.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 5;
y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 1;
y.delegate = self;

// Pin axis to left
y.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

I am trying to use -(BOOL)axis:(CPTAxis *)axis shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:(NSSet *)locations but is not getting called as suggested in [How to set custom tick marks in Core Plot to icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748996/how-to-set-custom-tick-marks-in-core-plot-to-icons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the delegate class conforms to the `<CPTAxisDelegate>` protocol and the method has the correct signature:

```
-(BOOL)axis:(nonnull CPTAxis *)axis shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:(nonnull CPTNumberSet *)locations;
```

Comment: Oops ! there was  mistake w.r.t method signature. Thank you Eric.